# Symfony2, FOSUserBundle, forgot password email not sending

Tags: php, email, symfony

I have my config.yml settings here:

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: Main\UserBundle\Entity\User
  resetting:
      email:
         from_email:
            address: noreply@mmerica.com
            sender_name: Mmerica Inc.
```

When I tried the "reset password" button it sends me to a page that says email has been sent to ....@email.com, and that there will be a reset link. However, I didn't receive any email. Is there another setting I should refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set swiftmailer in config.yml and set the parameters in parameters.yml

config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: xxxxxx
    database_user: xxxxxx
    database_password: xxxxxx 
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: "your SMTP server"
    mailer_user: "your SMTP user"
    mailer_password: "your SMTP user password"
    locale: en
    secret: ddddddddddddsfcdvfrergfergergergrggergrgregre
```

Comment: Same problem here. This answer does not help as it's the default setting. BTW, I'm using `mailer_transport: mail` and if I send emails from another controller, emails get sent.